# Attempting to create custom "post" template, getting a 500 internal server error

Tags: custom-post-types, customization

I've been following this tutorial:
http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/create-custom-single-post-templates-for-specific-posts-or-sections-in-wordpress/

To create a custom template for "post"-type webpages.  The tutorial calls for copying the contents of single.php into a blank sheet in which I define a template name (in this case it's "Series").

I have successfully made it appear as a selectable option in the "Post Attributes" section of the "Edit Post" screen, but when I select it and preview the post I'm met with a 500 internal server error.

At first I thought it was due to some type of php syntax, but after cleaning up opening and closing tags I don't see wh

I am using the HTML5 blank theme.  Code below:

```
    <?php
/*
 * Template Name: Series
 * Template Post Type: post, page, product
 */

 get_header(); 
 ?>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

        <?php
        // Start the loop.
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

            /*
             * Include the post format-specific template for the content. If you want to
             * use this in a child theme, then include a file called content-___.php
             * (where ___ is the post format) and that will be used instead.
             */
            get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

            // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
            if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
                comments_template();
            endif;

            // Previous/next post navigation.
            the_post_navigation( array(
                'next_text' => '<span class="meta-nav" aria-hidden="true">' . __( 'Next', 'twentyfifteen' ) . '</span> ' .
                    '<span class="screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Next post:', 'twentyfifteen' ) . '</span> ' .
                    '<span class="post-title">%title</span>',
                'prev_text' => '<span class="meta-nav" aria-hidden="true">' . __( 'Previous', 'twentyfifteen' ) . '</span> ' .
                    '<span class="screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Previous post:', 'twentyfifteen' ) . '</span> ' .
                    '<span class="post-title">%title</span>'
            ) );

        // End the loop.
        endwhile;
        ?>

        </main><!-- .site-main -->
    </div><!-- .content-area -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first step in this situations is to enable WP_DEBUG to get more info about the error, you can learn more here https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG